# Pandas series index as column name of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Task description**

I have a pandas series as follows:

```
   rank   loc
    0.0     AU     2
            US     1
    1.0     UK     1
            AU     3
            US     1
```

I wish to make a DataFrame with rank as the column name and loc as the index. The desired df would look as follows:

```
     0.0    1.0
AU    2      3
UK           1
US    1      1
```

I am happy with either NaN or 0 in rows where there are no values. Any help would be great!

Comment: df= df.unstack(level=0)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this series is called S.

First flatten it and convert to a dataframe and rename for easier access

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(S).to_records())
df.columns = ['rank', 'loc', 'counts']
```

Now group by *loc*, and loop over each group and create a dictionary, with "key" coming from *rank* and "value" coming from *counts*

For each group you will have this dictionary, which you can append to a *temp_list*, while *temp_indices* keep track of the index (in this case the value of *loc*)

Finally we can create a *result* dataframe out of the list of dictionaries (*temp_list*)  with indices coming from *temp_indices*

```
temp_list = list()
temp_indices = list()

for _name, _val in df.groupby('loc'):
    temp_dict = dict()
    for _, row in _val.iterrows():
        temp_dict.update({row['rank']: row['counts']})
    temp_indices.append(_name)
    temp_list.append(temp_dict)

result = pd.DataFrame(temp_list, index=temp_indices)
```

Comment: Thanks, but @BEN_YO one liner did the job!